# A Buffer of Lines at the Bottom in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I hate having my cursor at the very bottom of the editor panel when I'm coding. Is there a way to tell Eclipse to always show me the three or four lines below my cursor (or, in the case that I'm near the bottom of the file, to just show me empty lines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, I think there is no such functionality.